# TFS RM Package Path

Tags: tfs, artifactory, ms-release-management

I'm working on integrating a binary repository (Artifactory) into our release pipeline.  I plan to have our builds automatically add their build artifacts to the correct repo and then have TFS Release Management pull from that repo for release.  My question is, how to I get RM to pull from Artifactory?  It appears that RM will only work with artifacts on a UNC path.  I also tried adding a tool to the beginning of my release that gets the artifact but the release fails before any tool runs if the UNC path doesn't exists.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Can Artifactory not provide UNC access to the packages? ProGet can.